# Manipulação de String - split()

Tags: java, string

Existe alguma maneira de dar um `split()` numa `string` e na mesma linha pegar a posição que eu quero?

Por exemplo:

```
String nome = "Dan Lucio Prada";

String sobrenome = nome.split(" "); //aqui quero pegar só o sobrenome [Prada]
```

Comment: Apesar de ter respondido à pergunta considero que isso não tem qualquer interesse ou vantagem, principalmente no caso da resposta do Jéferson Bueno que obriga a fazer duas chamadas a `nome.split(" ");` e ter o código mais difícil de ser lido.

Comment: Concordo plenamente com o @ramaral, isso só serve para fins de estudo. Eu mostrei a solução daquela forma apenas porque fica mais dinâmico, pois não sabia se você ia ter sempre a mesma `string` ou ela poderia mudar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Todas as respostas estão corretas, porém eu acho interessante acrescentar que, levando em consideração que o sobrenome será sempre a **última palavra** da `string`, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
String nome = "Dan Lucio Prada";
EscreverSobrenome(nome); // A saída será "Prada"

String nome2 = "Joaquim Pedro Soares da Silva";
EscreverSobrenome(nome2); // A saída será "Silva"

public String EscreverSobrenome(String nome){
    sobrenome = nome.split(" ")[nome.split(" ").length - 1]; // Essa linha é a solução pro seu problema
    System.out.println(sobrenome);
}
```

Desse jeito não importa quantas palavras tenham, a variável `sobrenome` sempre receberá a última palavra.

Answer (score 4):

Tem, faça assim:

```
String nome = "Dan Lucio Prada";
String sobronome = nome.split(" ")[2];
```

É claro que isto só funciona se o nome tiver 3 palavras.

Comment: String[] nomes = nome.split(" ")
String sobronome = nomes[nomes.lenght()-1];

Comment: @ChristianBeregula Sim, eu era para colocar algo do género mas o AP quer numa só instrução.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, consegue em uma linha:

```
System.out.println("Dan Lucio Prada".split(" ")[2]);
```

Mas é muito melhor usar mais que uma linha e fazer direito:

```
String nome = "Dan Lucio Prada";
String[] partes = nome.split(" ");
System.out.println(partes[partes.length - 1]);
```

Até dá para fazer isto em uma linha também mas é ineficiente, então é melhor fazer do jeito certo.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/R2Wdmg). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ovamkkav-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/Split.java).

Answer (score 2):

Para registro e (talvez) serventia para alguém, neste caso não há necessidade em ter que fazer `split` da *string*. Não sei se a obrigatoriedade é usar `split` ou ter o último nome, mas sem usar `split` é possível fazer em uma única linha, algo assim:

```
sentence.substring(sentence.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1)
```

`sentence.lastIndexOf(" ")`, como é de simples entendimento, irá retornar o índice do último espaço na sentenção. Depois somamos `1`, posição da próxima letra que é a primeira letra do último nome. Com esta informação o [`substring(int beginIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-), iniciará desta primeira letra do nome e irá até o final da sentença/nome, sempre retornando a última palavra.

Por exemplo, isto:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String dan = "Dan Lucio Prada";
    System.out.println(lastWordFromSentence(dan));

    final String bruno = "Bruno César";
    System.out.println(lastWordFromSentence(bruno));

    final String name = "Bruno";
    System.out.println(lastWordFromSentence(name));
}

public static String lastWordFromSentence(final String sentence) {
    return sentence.substring(sentence.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
}
```

Gera este resultado:

```
Prada
César
Bruno
```

Fica como sugestão em casos que não é obrigatório o uso de `split` :)