# Ajuda em como pegar a ultima palavra de uma string e acrescentar ao inicio usando java

Tags: java, string

Eu tenho um nome completo: Jais Pereira Guedes Godofredo

O exemplo abaixo, eu pego a última palavra, mas como fazer pra imprimir com esse resultado: **Godofredo, Jais Pereira Guedes**

```
public class Aula1{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String nomeCompleto = "Jais Pereira Guedes Godofredo";
        String[] split = nomeCompleto.split(" ");
        String resultado = split[split.length - 1];
        System.out.println(resultado );
    }
}
```

Comment: Acho que é duplicata.

Comment: Relacionada: [Manipulação de String - split](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87810/91)

Comment: Pode ser relacionada em parte, fica a desejar outra `relacionada` que coloca a substring no inicio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oi @AmandaRJ. Já tive essa dúvida, vê se te ajuda isso, resolvi dessa maneira:

```
 *
 * @author marcia
 */
public class Aula1{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String nomeCompleto = "Jais Pereira Guedes Godofredo"; // Recebo o nome a ser tratado  
        int posicao = 0; // Posição do nome [0,1,2,3...], o nome está na posição 0  
        for (int i = 0; i < nomeCompleto.length(); i++) {
            if (nomeCompleto.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                posicao = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(nomeCompleto.substring(posicao, nomeCompleto.length()) + ", " + nomeCompleto.substring(0, posicao));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    String sentenca = "Jais Pereira Guedes Godofredo";
    int index= sentenca.lastIndexOf(" ");
    String restoSentenca = (sentenca.substring(0, index));
    String ultimaPalavra = (sentenca.substring(index+1));
    String novaSentenca = ultimaPalavra + ", " + restoSentenca;
    System.out.println(novaSentenca);
```

[exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/3MqVsr)

Answer (score -1):

Utilize o lastIndexOf e depois o substring

Segue uns exemplos:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_lastindexof.htm

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm

Exemplos:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test {

public static void main(String args[]) {

  String Str = new String("Welcome to Tutorialspoint.com");

  System.out.print("Return Value :" );

  System.out.println(Str.substring(10) );


}
}

import java.io.*;
public class Test {

public static void main(String args[]) {

  String Str = new String("Welcome to Tutorialspoint.com");

  System.out.print("Found Last Index :" );

  System.out.println(Str.lastIndexOf( 'o' ));

}
}
```

Fonte: www.tutorialspoint.com/java

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)